# Zend Framework 2: Set Layout using MvcEvent

Tags: php, layout, zend-framework2

I want to change the layout using an mvc event. I've tried the following:

```
// $event instanceof \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent
$serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$controllerLoader = $serviceManager->get('ControllerLoader');
$controllerLoader->addInitializer(function ($controller) {

    $controller->layout('layout/example');
    // OR THIS
    $controller->getEvent()->getViewModel()->setTemplate('layout/example');
});
```

My aproaches don't produce any errors notices or something. Not even if `layout/example` doesn't exist. Why is it possible to change the layout from inside a controller with `$this->layout()` but not from outside with `$controller->layout()`?

I also tried it this way:

```
// $event instanceof \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent
$serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$renderingStrategy = $serviceManager->get('DefaultRenderingStrategy');
$renderingStrategy->setLayoutTemplate('layout/example');
```

This also does not throw out any errors but does not change anything.

How can I switch the layout from outside of the controller during runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

aww, it was so easy: simply call it directly on the event..

```
// $event instanceof \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent
$event->getViewModel()->setTemplate('layout/example');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//$this instanceof Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController
$this->layout('layout/example');
```